# Toast message using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, toast

I was wondering if it's possible to reproduce this toast message that Apple uses when you add an album to your collection in Apple Music (well, in fact I don't really know how to name this grey box with a tick in the middle of screen, but 'toast' seems to fit). Any ideas how to implement this using Swift?

[image: toast]

Comment: what did you try?
did you search on github?
this is a general question, elaborate and be specifc so people can help you.

Comment: Instead of just flagging it can some point out to the right gihub tool or to other similar stackOverFlow question?

Comment: In case you're still wondering, it's called a HUD (Heads Up Display) and if you google "ios hud" you'll find tons of open source libraries. Leaving this here since I searched for ages to find out what it was called.

Comment: @DavidChu I will definitely look up for this! Thank you for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Gordonium's answer in Swift class

```
public class LoaderOverlay {

    private var loaderOverlayView: UIView!

    class var shared: LoaderOverlay {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: LoaderOverlay = LoaderOverlay()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    private func setup() {
        loaderOverlayView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 100))
        loaderOverlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        loaderOverlayView.alpha = 0.8
        loaderOverlayView.layer.cornerRadius = 8

        let indicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView.init(activityIndicatorStyle: .White)
        indicator.tag = 1
        loaderOverlayView.addSubview(indicator)
        indicator.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(loaderOverlayView.frame)/2.0, CGRectGetHeight(loaderOverlayView.frame)/2.0)
        indicator.startAnimating()
    }

    // MARK:- Public
    public func show() {
        if loaderOverlayView == nil {
            self.setup()
        } else {
            let indicator = loaderOverlayView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIActivityIndicatorView
            indicator.startAnimating()
        }

        if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window {
            window!.addSubview(loaderOverlayView)
            loaderOverlayView.center = window!.center
        }
    }

    public func hide() {
        let indicator = loaderOverlayView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIActivityIndicatorView
        indicator.stopAnimating()

        loaderOverlayView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Usage:
to show

```
LoaderOverlay.shared.show()
```

to hide

```
LoaderOverlay.shared.hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Obj-C and not Swift but I have an old project with something like this in it. The UI isn't the same but I'm sure it's easy to change to something that you want. It adds an acitivty indicator (spinner) rather than a tick on a dark background. You could call this code from anywhere and it will display as it adds it to the main window. If you only need it in one place then just add it to the presenting view.

Call this code when you want to show it:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 100)];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myView.alpha = 0.8;
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

UIActivityIndicatorView *act = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[myView addSubview:act];
act.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(myView.frame)/2.0, CGRectGetHeight(myView.frame)/2.0);
[act startAnimating];

UIWindow *mainWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
[mainWindow addSubview:myView];
myView.center = mainWindow.center;
```